# After latest update the java file from the gui do strange things

Tags: codenameone

Yesterday i updated to the latest version of CodenameOne.
I like the new version of the new GUI but... 2 problems:

1. When I try to add a command from the new GUI, the code created to the java file creates an error. If I remember correct it says ";" missing. So i create now the command by code.
2. On buttons I create a new Action Event. It is created to the jave file, but it never run the code to the onButton_1ActionEvent handler. I tried with debug and never goes in there. It works perfect when i create the Action event from the code myself.

So is it a bug, or i do something wrong? Plugin Version is 3.5.5

Thank you

Comment: I suggest adding more information on the error to help us track it.

Comment: As i said above, after updating, adding an action event through the gui builder is not working. It works if i add the event by code.  I donot know how more specific i can be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We released 3.5.6 yesterday which is still undergoing verification right now. When submitting issues/problems we need the version of the GUI builder from the about menu, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Gui Builder version is 1.15

Comment: updated to 3.5.6 and to gui builder 1.17 - The first problem solved and commands work as it should. But the second problem exists.

Comment: I see the problem, we need to review our release script... I guess we'll need a new release

Comment: Looking at this more deeply please try this. Right click the project, select properties and click OK in the dialog. Try to build the project. Is the code generated correctly now?

Comment: The code for the button created and for  button's action event. The problem is that when I click the button the action event is not been triggered.

Comment: Did you try doing what I asked?

Comment: Now i did it and it worked. Thank you. but what it was the problem exacly? I tried to clean and rebuild the project

Comment: The CodeNameOneBuildClient.jar had the bug. It is updated when you send builds to the server or in other odd situations. We need to make its update process more intuitive

Comment: I didnt have this problem with version 3.5.3. But thanks anyway for your help. Continue the good work!!!

Comment: This was a regression we added in 3.5.5.